# Queue of type struct gives error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, queue

```
typedef struct _Hello
{
char mString[10];
}hello;
```

.H File

```
 class A{
    void checkSize();
    queue<hello> queue1;
    queue<int> queue2;
    };
```

.cpp File

```
void A::checkSize()
{
   queue1.size(); //a very large erroneous value
   queue2.size(); 0
}
```

Does any one knows why queue1 gives an erroneous value? This program is running in a threaded fashion and I have checked the whole program, queue1 has not been initialized elsewhere. The error goes away when I make the queue1 static. 
Actually i was pushing an object of the struct to the queue and it was giving an "access violation writing location".

Comment: `hello` is a variable (of type `_Hello`). `queue` template expects a type, not a variable, as its parameter. You might want to read about `typedef` in your favorite C++ textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is messed up. Instead of

```
Struct _Hello {
  char[10] mString;
} hello;
```

it should be

```
struct hello {
  char mString[10];
};
```

(arguably, mString should be a `std::string`, but one thing at a time). The important bits are:

- `struct` with a lower-case `s` -- C++ is case-sensitive
- The array declaration had the extents in the wrong place.
- unlike in C, `struct hello { ... };` declares a type `hello`, not just `struct hello`.
- Like in C, `struct _Hello { ... } hello;` does not declare a type `hello` but a variable `hello`.
- `_Hello` is a [reserved identifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) (see bottom of the page) that you're not allowed to use because it is reserved for the implementation.

Oh, and you forgot the `;` after the class definition of `A`.

Comment: Ok, I have made the changes its a sort-of puesdo code. Kindly have a look at the last paragraph, let me know if you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem at hand :)

Comment: The code you originally posted would not even have compiled. Why your real code behaves strangely is a question I cannot answer without the relevant bits of that code (an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). I can wildly guess that you're writing beyond the end of a buffer that happens to lie directly before the `A` object in memory and thereby smashed the queue, or doing the same to a member of that object that lies before the queue in the object, but I do not have enough information to give reliable advice.